# Search and edit text documents, and assign to variable in Mac terminal

Tags: mac, bash, terminal

So if I saved system_profile to a text document, how would I be able to delete all but one section? Or delete quotes around it? Then how would I assign certain text to a variable to check certain things?

Example:
If I save system_profile to a text document, how would I search through to find how much ram I have, and assign that to the variable 'ram'? Also, could I have it search for and delete certain characters? For example have a script delete all quotation marks?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide examples of what you want?  Your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: I agree with Chris. Can you provide a sample of what system_profile will look like? The sample needs to be as accurate as possible to ensure that the solution will work correctly.

Comment: This question is really three separate questions.  You've asked about performing a text search, editing a file, and variable assignment.  Please ask your questions separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for words in a file using grep.

Example:

```
cat system_profile | grep ram
```

This will return the line in system_profile that contains the pattern "ram".
You'll probably need to run the command and look at the return before you can develop an understanding of what to do next.  If all you want is a portion of the file, you can perform a search and redirect your output to a new file.

Example:

```
cat system_profile | grep ram -A 5 > system_ram
```

This will give you the line that contains "ram" and the five lines after it.

You can replace characters thru the utility sed.

Example:

```
sed -i 's/old/new/g' system_profile
```

To eliminate double quotes ("):

```
sed -i 's/"//g' system_profile
```

Comment: Is it possible to also include the next line or few lines? Or prior lines? And if it appears several times how do i specify which occourance? Then what about saving it to a variable?

Comment: As Bandit has shown, it's possible to include lines before and after your search returns positive.  If you post the lines in your file just before and after the value you want to save, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to select between different occurrences, but hopefully this will help.

```
x=$(cat system_profile | grep ram -A 5)
```

The above code will save the line containing ram and the next 5 lines after it.  For getting lines before, use `-a` instead of `-A`.

I guess `grep` supports selecting a limited number of lines (i.e. stop after the first occurrence of `ram`).  If that is what you are looking for, use the `-m 1` (where one is the number of occurrences to find before stopping) option for grep.

Alternatively, you can modify your grep search if the two (or more) lines getting selected are not identical.  Just change `ram` to whatever you need to match (put it in quotes if it is more than one word)